# Soundcloud python api wrapped_resource error on Mac OS

Tags: python, macos, api, sdk, soundcloud

I'm trying to follow [this example](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#search) in the Soundcloud Python api docs:

I'm on Mac OS 10.10, and get this error when I try to run the example code. My api key does work and some of the other examples do work.

```
import soundcloud

# create a client object with your app credentials
client = soundcloud.Client(client_id='YOUR_CLIENT_ID')

# find all sounds of buskers licensed under 'creative commons share     alike'
tracks = client.get('/tracks', q='buskers', license='cc-by-sa')
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "music.py", line 7, in <module>
    tracks = client.get('/tracks', q='buskers')
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.10-intel/egg/soundcloud/client.py", line 130, in _request
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.10-intel/egg/soundcloud/resource.py", line 52, in wrapped_resource
TypeError: decode() argument 1 must be string, not None
```

Comment: Have the same trouble, try to solve it since yesterday evening.. anyone ?